Can I safely use floating apps?
I find floating apps very useful (e.g. Floating Timer, Floating Notes) but I'm concerned about security.
We're told to be careful and only install apps from developers we trust. But we don't have any way of knowing that a seemingly trustworthy app won't become compromised – expecting a user to make a correct assessment makes no sense.
Questions:

How big a security risk is this, actually?
Is there anything I can do to minimise the risks while using the apps? (Or should I just replace these with non-floating apps?)


Possible dupe: What are the risks of allowing an app the "Draw over other apps" permission? (not yet answered)
